# zapier and google firebase integration to send emails

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I have a zapier account and I want to use zapier to send an email every time a new document is added to the emails collection. I am currently trying to set it up but I am running into an issue where the trigger setup is not correct or the account is not recognizing when a new document is added. It is not seeing the document that I created while setting up the zapier.

here is my firebase:
[image: firebase doc added]

Here is the zapier account:

[image: Here is what my zapier query looks like]

This is what I am getting when testing:

[image: testing results image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because there is no field called `createTime` inside the document. The field that contains the timestamp is called `timestamp`. So your query should look like this:

```
"orderBy": [{
    "field": {
        "fieldPath": "timestamp"
    },
    "direction": "DESCENDING"
}]
```

Comment: Hey ojandali. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?